# OpenCL AMD compiling GL examples

Tags: compiler-errors, opencl

I am trying to compile the AMD examples and keep receiving the errors

```
In file included from /home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-     lnx64/include/GL/glew.h:1138,
             from SimpleGL.hpp:103,
             from SimpleGL.cpp:93:
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:231: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:231: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:231: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:271: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:271: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:271: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:354: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:354: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:354: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:360: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:363: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:364: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:365: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:366: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:367: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:368: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:372: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:373: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:374: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:375: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:376: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:377: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/home/james/ati-stream-sdk-v2.3-lnx64/include/GL/glu.h:384: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

I tracked this down to the function definition

```
void APIENTRY gluQuadricCallback ( 
GLUquadric          *qobj,  
GLenum              which,  
void                (CALLBACK* fn)());
```

I am not terribly familiar with cpp so I am not sure if this is in proper form or not. 
Has any one else had this problem?
My system is Ubuntu 64-bit 10.10 Maverick.

Comment: I solved my problem by replacing their glu headers with my systems headers. I would still like to know why the function above is incorrect. To me it looks like it says it takes a pointer to a function with no parameters that returns void. What is wrong with the original function definition.

Comment: I can only assume one of the types (`GLUquadric` or `CALLBACK`) isn't defined.